# Xamarin.forms store Images as list in firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app which uses firebase storage to upload Images. I can upload single image to firebase Storage using

```
string ImageURl = await firebaseStorageHelper.UploadFile(file.GetStream(), Path.GetFileName(file.Path));
```

and In my `FirebaseStorageHelper` class is like

```
 public async Task<string> UploadFile(Stream fileStream, string fileName)
        {
            var imageUrl = await firebaseStorage
                .Child("UploadedImages")
                .Child(fileName)
                .PutAsync(fileStream);
            return imageUrl;
        }

 public async Task<string> GetFile(string fileName)
    {
        return await firebaseStorage
            .Child("UploadedImages")
            .Child(fileName)
            .GetDownloadUrlAsync();
    }
```

What I am trying to do is upload multiple images and store it as a list in firebase storage and also need to get the images as list. Is it possible? What change should I do? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong with listing all the children using the [Firebase List API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/list-files) and then download them? Do you need to scope it somehow per user or what are you looking for more specifically?

Comment: @Cheesebaron What I am trying to do is user can select multiple images from gallery, Then the list of thease multiple images needs to upload as list into firebase storage. I will show the images to set as itemsource for carousal view in another page by getting the URLs as a list

Comment: Sure, but where is your issues in doing so?

Comment: @Cheesebaron How can I Upload the image list ?  what changes should I do in UploadFile task?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I can upload single image and get its URL. I want it both upload and download in the format of list.

Comment: Then change your methods to accept a list of files to upload and change the get file method to return all the children instead of a specific one for the "UploadedImages" folder. Have you read the docs I sent you? If so have you tried any of it?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Ok thanks sir. I am going through the link you provided.

Comment: Hi , have the problem been solved ?

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT No bro. I didn't able to save images as list in firebase